# How can I prove this exercise using Hahn Banach theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, hahn-banach-theorem

> Let $X$ be a normed space, $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$ and $x\in X\setminus Y$. I need to prove that there exists $\bar f\in X^*$ s.t. $\bar f=0$ on $Y$ and $\bar f(x)=\inf \{||x-y||: y\in Y\}=:d(x,Y)$

My idea was the following. Let me define $$p=d(\cdot, Y):X\setminus Y\rightarrow \Bbb{R}; x\mapsto d(x,Y)$$ and $$f:Y\rightarrow \Bbb{R}; y\mapsto 0$$Then clearly $p$ is sublinear and $f$ is linear such that $f\leq q$. Now applying Hahn-Banach theorem we get that there exists $\bar f\in X^*$ such that $\bar f(x)=f(x)=0$ for all $x\in Y$ and $\bar f(x)\leq p(x)=d(x,Y)$ for all $x\in X$.

Now I thought that I would be done if I could show that $\bar f=p(x)$ for all $x\in X\setminus Y$. But I don't see how to do this. Could someone help me?

**Edit**
Could I finish the proof as follows: Let me assume $\bar f(x)<d(x,Y)$ for all $x\in X$ then pick $x\in Y$ so $$0=\bar f(x)<0$$ which is a contradiction, hence $\bar f(x)=p(x)$?

Comment: It cannot be the case that $\overline{f}$ is a linear functional since its output is always nonnegative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, as a general comment, you are mixing $x$ as a fixed element in the original statement and after that you use it as a general element of $X$. That will most likely confuse you.

Second, applying Hahn-Banach that way there are two problems:

- taking $\bar f=0$ is a perfectly acceptable extension and so you miss the possibility of getting the concrete choice for $\tilde f(x)$.
- you have no guarantee that $\bar f$ will be bounded.

Third, note that your argument does not use that $Y$ is closed, which is essential for the original statement to be true.

Fourth, the definition you are trying is not linear!

Instead, you could consider the space $\tilde Y=\operatorname{span}\{Y,x\}$, and define $f(y+\lambda x)=\lambda$ (this is well-defined because $x\not\in Y$ guarantees that $y,x$ are linearly independent). Let us look at the norm of $f$ (note that the case $\lambda=0$ cannot contribute to the sup):
\begin{align}
\|f\|
&=\sup\Big\{\frac{|f(y+\lambda x)|}{\|y+\lambda x\|}:\ y\in Y,\ \lambda\ne0\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\frac{|\lambda |}{\|y+\lambda x\|}:\ y\in Y,\ \lambda\ne0\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\frac{1}{\|y/\lambda+  x\|}:\ y\in Y,\ \lambda\ne0\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\Big\{\frac{1}{\|y-  x\|}:\ y\in Y\Big\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac{1}{\inf\{\|y-  x\|:\ y\in Y\}}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)}.
\end{align}
Now we know that $f$ is bounded on $\tilde Y$, and then by Hahn-Banach there exists $\bar g\in X^*$ with $\|\bar g\|=\|f\|$ and $\bar g|_{\tilde Y}=f$. This gives
$$
\bar g(y)=0,\qquad y\in Y,\qquad\qquad \bar g(x)=1.
$$
Now you can simply define
$$
\bar f(z)=\operatorname{dist}(x,Y)\,\bar g(z). 
$$

Comment: how do you get to your $f$? It looks somehow magic to me

Comment: What's unclear? An element of $\tilde Y$ is, by definition, of the form $y+\lambda x$. Given such element, you need to produce a number in a linear way. One way is to do it $y+\lambda x\longmapsto \lambda$.

Comment: And how do you see that we need this $\tilde Y=\operatorname{span}\{Y,x\}$ I would not have seen it

Comment: You want $f$ to be zero on $Y$ and nonzero on $x$. I chose $1$ for the value at $x$.

Comment: Yes. The $f$ in your question is $0$ on $Y$, but you have no control over what it does outside of $Y$.

Comment: ah I see perfect. And sorry another question, the Hahn-Banach theorem tells me that there exists $\bar g\in X^*$ such that $||\bar g||=||f||$ and $\bar g=f$ on $\tilde Y$ right, but I don't need this two properties to say that $\bar g(y)=0$ for $y\in Y$ and $\bar g (x)=1$, so I mean why do I need this two properties of $\bar g$ are those only nice to have? With nice to have I mean they follow from Hahn Banach but are not really used in this exercise.

Comment: They are absolutely used. The little start superscript on $X^*$ in the statement of the question requires that $\bar f$ is bounded. Without that, this would be a (very easy) linear algebra exercise, not related at all with functional analysis.

Comment: For completeness you should mention that $f$ is well-defined on $\tilde Y$, that is, if $y,y'\in Y$ and $\lambda x+ y=\lambda' x+ y'$ then $\lambda =\lambda'$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami ah I see it thanks!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: good point, I have clarified that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami can a similar proof be carried out if $Y$ is only a nonempty, closed, convex and proper subset (which might not even contain $0$)? I think the absorption of $\lambda$ when computing the $\sup$ uses the fact that $Y$ is a subspace right?

Comment: No. If $Y$ is a closed ball, then $f|_Y=0$ implies $f=0$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for the reply. In the case where $Y$ is only a closed and convex proper subset, can we still find some $f \in X^*$ such that $\sup_{y \in Y} f(y) \leq f(x) - d(x,Y)$ somehow?

Comment: Yes, what you want is $d(x,Y)\leq f(x-y)$ for all $y\in Y$. The closed convex set $x-Y$ does not contain $0$, so it can be separated from zero by some $f\in X^*$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks. But doesn't that only gives $0 = f(0) < f(x-y)$ for all $y \in Y$? Can you please elaborate a bit more on why we in fact have $d(x,Y) \leq f(x-y)$? for all $y \in Y$?

Comment: Yes. There is $c>0$ and $g\in X^*$ such that $c<g(x-y)$ for all $Y$. Now define $f=\frac1c\,d(x,Y)\,g$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the quotient space $X / Y$, which is a normed space with norm $\|[x]\| = d(x, Y)$. By the Hahn Banach theorem, there is $f \in (X / Y)^*$ such that $\|f\| = \|[x]\| = d(x, Y)$. There is an isometric isomorphism $(X / Y)^* \approx Y^{\perp}$ given by $f \mapsto f \circ \pi$, where $\pi : X \to X / Y$ is defined by $\pi x = [x]$. Thus $\overline{f} := f \circ \pi$ is your desired functional.